# How to check if you are using Karma?

Tags: javascript, testing, karma-runner

How can I check if I'm running my script on Karma?

When I'm on Karma, I tried with this:

```
var path = '';

if (typeof window.karma !== 'undefined') {
  path += 'base/';
} 

alert(typeof window.karma); // undefined
```

I also tried with this:

```
var path = '';

if (typeof window.__karma__ !== 'undefined') {
  path += 'base/';
} 

alert(typeof window.__karma__); // still undefined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post at least the `karma` configuration? Your second attempt should work in theory but if it's not working there's something wrong the the configuration I guess.

Comment: It now works with the second one and I don't understand why!

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you need to check this?

Comment: Perhaps author loads runs tests as a separate `.html` page locally, and uses Karma somewhere else. At least it is the way I got here :). It's easier to debug as a local page. `http://localhost:9876/debug.html` might help, though.

Comment: Looks like the second variant is what are you looking for [`karma-runner github`](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/client/karma.js#L71)

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you use it this way

```
var path = '';

if ((<any>window).__karma__ !== undefined) {
    path += 'base/';
} 

alert(typeof window.__karma__); // still undefined
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will be more careful.

Answer (score 1):

Karma has configurations which allows to include any lib files,
so there you can include your own test specific JS.

In your case it could be a simple flag injected in the global context and used later in some certain test.

https://karma-runner.github.io/6.3/config/files.html